# Back button on the browser not taking to the right tab in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js

I am using v-tabs in my app. The issue I am facing here is that on users tab I have links which take me further to another page. But when I click on back button on the browser to go back to the previous page which is the users tab page it takes to the officers tab instead of the users tab. Please help me fix this problem.

```
<v-tabs v-model="tabsOption"
     centered
     color="black"
     slider-color="red">
 <v-tab  href="#officers">Officers</v-tab>
 <v-tab  href="#users">Users</v-tab>
</v-tabs>

<script>
      export default {
        data: function() {
          return {
            tabsOption: 'officers'
          }
        },
        created: function() {
          this.tabsOption = window.location.hash.slice(1) || 'officers' || 'users';
        },
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like your template has a typo `v-model="tabs-option"`. should it not be `v-model="tabs-options"`?

Comment: @sthotakura is right, but you used an underscore in the variable name (i.e. `tabs_options`), so your template should probably look like `<v-tabs v-model="tabs_options">`

Comment: @sthotakura Sorry that was a typo while pasting code on stackoverflow. I have fixed the question.

Comment: @morphatic that was a typo in the question. I have fixed the question.

Comment: @user12763413 your created function still updates `tabs_options`?

Comment: @sthotakura sorry about that. Please check now.

Comment: @sthotakura is there a way to get the url of the previous page when back browser button is clicked?

Comment: `tabs-option` is not a valid Javascript variable, you probably should change it to something like `tabsOption` or `tabs_option`

Comment: @sthotakura I changed the code as you suggested but still the same issue.

Comment: are you using `vue-router`? If so you could hook into navigation guards - instead of created - to inspect route hash value and set it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `v-tab-item` you can combine the `:to` attribute in the `v-tab` with the `value` attribute in the `v-tab-item` by using a hash link, like this:

```
<v-tabs>
    <v-tab :to="'#alpha'">Tab A</v-tab>
    <v-tab :to="'#bravo'">Tab B</v-tab>
    <v-tab-item value="alpha">Tab A content</v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item value="bravo">Tab B content</v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>
```

If you click "Tab B" and then a click some link that takes you to a new page, and then go back, either via the browser back button, or a history.back(), the "Tab B" will be active and its content "Tab B content" will be visible